# O que são lambda expressions? E qual a sacada em usá-las?

Tags: c#, expressões-lambda

Quando comecei a usar LINQ vi que poderia usar as famosas **lambda expressions**.

Até sei que `x => x * x` é uma lambda expression, mas não consegui explicar para um colega o que realmente são, e qual a vantagem em usá-las.

Então vos pergunto:

O que são lambda expressions? E qual a sacada em usá-las?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

### O que são expressões lambda?

Expressões lambda são aquelas do tipo A vai para B, significando primordialmente uma transformação. No C#, existem lambdas constantes, e multiparametrizadas.

No C#, uma expressão lambda, pode ser convertida para:

- um `Delegate`: é um método compilado, que pode ser executado, e passado como se fosse uma variável para quem necessitar. Também chamados de métodos anônimos, por não possuirem um identificador próprio.
- um `Expression<>` que representa uma árvore de expressões que denotam em forma de estrutura de dados a transformação que representa a expressão lambda.

### Uso na forma de Delegate

Quando convertida para um delegate, a lambda pode ser passada como se fosse uma variável. Uma lambda produz um delegate de um tipo específico que depende do contexto em que ela for criada.

As chamadas abaixo geram delegates de tipos diferentes:

```
// delegate gerado do tipo Func<string, bool>
Func<string, bool> func = s => s == null;

// delegate gerado do tipo Predicate<string>
Predicate<string> pred = s => s == null;
```

Assim sendo cada delegate de tipo distinto pode ser passado como se fosse uma variável comum, sendo possível chamar esses métodos assim:

```
pred("string to test");
```

Todos os delegates, independete do tipo específico, herdam da classe `Delegate`.

**Closures em delegates**

Lambdas podem apresentar em seu conteúdo, variáveis presentes no método que a constrói, aprisionando esta variável, na forma de uma referência para a mesma. Isso também é possível ao construir delegates inline.

```
int i = 0;
Action incrementa = () => i++;
incrementa();
// neste ponto a variável i, terá seu valor incrementado
```

Isso é uma ferramenta muito poderosa, e também perigosa, principalmente quando usada em loops, usando-se o valor da variável de iteração.

```
var listFunc = new Func<int>[10];
for (int it = 0; it < 10; it++)
    listFunc[it] = () => it;
// todos os elementos de listFunc retornam 10
// pois a variável it, neste ponto vale 10,
// e todos os delegates referenciam a mesma variável
```

### Uso na forma de Expression

Quando se fala em expressão lambda, é comum se passar batido por esta forma de utilizá-las, mas que é amplamente usada por frameworks como o `EntityFramework` e o `MVC`, ambos da Microsoft.

O LINQ suporta a interface `IQueryable`, que se baseia no uso de lambdas transformadas em estrutura de dados, as quais analiza afim de criar uma query que possa ser executada no banco de dados.

Assim como essas bibliotecas fazem, é possível ler essa estrutura de dados gerada a partir de uma expressão lambda, usando as classes presentes no namespace [System.Linq.Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Além disso, esses lambdas na forma de `Expression` podem ser copiadas e alteradas, e depois disso compiladas, sendo uma das formas de ser gerar **código executável dinamicamente**. Também é possível criar um árvore de expressões do zero, gerando dinamicamente métodos inteiros, usando o método [Compile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345362%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), presente na classe `Expression<T>`.

**Closures em árvores de expressão (expression trees)**

Expression trees podem, assim como os delegates, possuir em seu código, referências para variáveis do contexto em que são construidas. Assim sendo, a referência à variável fica aprisionada em um nó da árvore de expressões, o que permite ler o valor dessa variável, e manter a semântica ao compilar esta árvore de expressão.

Comment: Miguel, as closures não são exclusivas das expressões lambda. O métodos anónimos também têm esta funcionalidade.

Comment: @PauloMorgado Do jeito que eu disse, realmente ficou parecendo que essa é a única forma de fazer closures... vou editar. Valeu!

Comment: Ótima explicação, Miguel.

Answer (score 24):

Em essência, a vantagem (no C#) em usá-las é poder transportar pequenas funções como valores.

Em essência. Porque elas envolvem várias outras vantagens.

Na verdade, `x => x * x` não é SÓ uma Lambda Expression, é também conhecida como uma função anônima, e pode assim ser usada como qualquer outra função. Você pode até declará-la assim:

```
Func<int, int> aoQuadrado = x => x * x;
```

E poderia executá-la numa lista, por exemplo:

```
Enumerable.Range(1, 101).Select(aoQuadrado).ToList();
```

O que produziria um IEnumerable com os quadrados dos números de 1 a 100 (`Enumerable.Range` é exclusivo, ou seja, não inclui o último número -- nesse caso, 101 -- em suas operações).

Isso é equivalente a isso (o que é, essencialmente, a mesma coisa, de forma imperativa ao invés de funcional):

```
int AoQuadrado(int n)
{
    return n * n;
}

var quadrados = new List<int>();
for (int i = 0; i < 101; i++) quadrados.Add(AoQuadrado(i));
```

Aliás, tanto métodos quanto funções anônimas (ou lambda) são funções, ou seja, você poderia fazer isso também:

```
int AoQuadrado(int n)
{
    return n * n;
}

var quadrados = from i in Enumerable.Range(1, 101).Select(AoQuadrado).ToList();
```

Até porque isso é perfeitamente valido:

```
int AoQuadrado(int n)
{
    return n * n;
}

Func<int, int> aoQuadrado = AoQuadrado;
```

Isto costuma chamar-se "funções de primeira classe". É a possibilidade de usar funções como valores, e assim, poder transportá-las mais facilmente.

**Resumindo:** O principal uso delas é poder transportar pequenas funções como valores, eu diria.

Comment: Vale ressaltar outros aspectos das expressões lambda, como Expression Trees, a geração de closures, entre outras, como descrito na minha resposta.

Comment: @MiguelAngelo Está certo, mas minha resposta foi focada no uso delas no C# (e no LINQ, como aparentava ser o foco do autor da pergunta). Não que Expression Trees e Closures não sejam importantes (especialmente Closures que são um conceito importantíssimo), mas acho que são conceitos que vão muito além do escopo da pergunta.

Comment: Não acho que seja o foco, principalmente por causa do LINQ... LINQ to objects usa lambdas na forma de delagates, mas LINQ to Entities, LINQ to SQL entre outros usam lambdas na forma de expression trees.

Comment: @MiguelAngelo É uma forma válida de ver. Como eu citei no chat, minha resposta foi um dardo e a sua uma bola de boliche. As duas acertaram o alvo da pergunta.

Comment: André, estás a confundir as expressões lambda com os delegates que são uma das traduções possíveis. Como o @MiguelAngelo chamou a atenção, também podem ser traduzidas para árvores de expressões.

Answer (score 13):

Uma expressão lambda é uma maneira concisa de declarar uma função ou subrotina. Num mundo orientado a objetos, é bastante similar a um objeto que tem um método só.

Existem duas vantagens principais de se usar uma expressão lambda ao invés de uma função ou método definida separadamante:

1. Simplicidade. Para que dar um nome a algo que só vai ser usado uma vez mesmo?
2. Escopo léxico. Funções lambda podem automaticamente usar todas as variáveis do escopo atual. Por exemplo:

   ```
   int y = 10;
   Func<int,int> f = (x => x + y);
   ```

   `f` é uma função que soma 10 ao seu argumento. Para fazer algo equivalente usando classes, precisariamos criar uma classe nova, criar um campo "y" nessa classe, inicializar esse campo no construtor da classe e passar o 10 como parâmetro na hora de criar o `f`. Usando funções anônimas isso tudo vem de graça.

Comment: +1 boa resposta - forneceste a informação solicitada, sem se prolongar em detalhes. E a comparação com "um objeto de um método só" é muito relevante - antes de termos lambdas em C#, era exatamente isso o que fazíamos.

Answer (score 11):

Em geral **lambda** significa passar uma função como argumento para outra função (definição dada para JavaScript, e se estende à todas as linguagens funcionais):

Em tradução livre:

> Lambda basicamente significa usar uma função como argumento numa chamada à outra função. Lambda é uma buzzword popular em programação funcional e é muito usada. O pior é que, ela é usada a como se todo mundo conhecesse seu real significado. Então, se você ver algo como "Aqui iremos usar uma expressão lambda", significa que eles estarão apenas passando uma função como um argumento.
>
> Visualmente, em psuedo-código, Lambda é representado pelo símbolo λ, a 11a letra do alfabeto Grego. Você também poderá ver nomes de variáveis como lambda para indicar que a mesma receberá uma função.

http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Functional_Javascript#quickIDX3

A sacada em usá-las é poder ter a função lambda executada em outro momento (É assim que **callbacks** funcionam em JavaScript).

Por exemplo, se é necessário fazer alguma computação dentro/depois que um certo evento assíncrono (como uma requisição http) é executado, utilizamos uma expressão lambda (callback) na a função. Eventos assíncronos são importantes no senso de que eles não barram o programa de executar :)

Answer (score 8):

Guilherme, esta é uma boa pergunta e que demandaria uma resposta muito extensa. Foi tentar ser  breve, e para isso foi deixar de fora muita coisa, tudo bem?

> O que são lambda expressions?

São, por definição, funções anônimas. Eu gosto de pensar em expressões lambda como funções de matemática. Você tem os parâmetros de entrada e o corpo da função, por exemplo:
f(x) = x * 2

Do lado esquerdo você define o que a função recebe, do lado direito o que ela faz.

> E qual a sacada em usá-las?

IMHO, a maior vantagem é poder enviar funções como argumentos para métodos. O maior exemplo disso está no Linq, como você comentou. Veja:

```
cidades.Where(x => x.Nome == "Florianópolis");
```

Vamos ver a assinatura do método `Where`:

```
public static IQueryable<TSource> Where<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> predicate);
```

O primeiro argumento é necessário porque ele é um extension method, então vamos deixar de lado por enquanto. Porém, veja o segundo. É uma expressão onde o tipo dela seja o tipo da coleção e que ela retorne um boolean.
Desta forma, qualquer expressão lambda que esteja de acordo com estas restrições pode ser enviada como parâmetro.

O legal disso é que você pode utilizar todo esse potencial no seu código, não precisa deixá-lo apenas no framework.

Answer (score 6):

Expressões lambda são nada mais nada menos do que tipos de métodos que você codifica de forma resumida, sem especificar toda a estrutura de um método. Na verdade, elas retornam uma referência para aquela funcionalidade codificada.

Isso é muito comum no LINQ, pois quando você filtra uma coleção você basicamente quer passar um método que decide se um objeto deve ou não estar entre os filtrados. Por exemplo, suponha que você tem uma coleção de objetos da seguinte classe

```
public class Cliente
{
    public int ClienteID { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    /* Outros membros */
}
```

E então você quer somente aqueles que possuem `ClienteID` par por exemplo. Então você usa o LINQ da seguinte forma:

```
var clientesFiltrados = listaClientes.where(verificaIdPar);
```

Esse `verificaIdPar` aponta para um método que pode verificar se um `ClienteID` é par. Mas pense um pouco: para codificar esse metodo normalmente, você teria que colocá-lo em uma classe e tudo, referenciá-lo e então passar ele para o `where` e dificilmente usaria outra vez. Para isso expressões lambda simplificam sua vida, você pode simplesmente colocar uma expressão lambda no lugar, que ela retorna uma referência para o método que possui a funcionalidade descrita na expressão lambda.

Perceba também que você pode referenciar expressões lambda por variáveis do tipo delegate.E é na verdade isso que esses métodos do LINQ fazem: esperam um delegate que aponte para um método que filtra, que seleciona, ou qualquer outra operação, e então por simplicidade usamos expressões lambda.

Answer (score 5):

Acredito que o conceito é mais importante do que a forma como ele é implementado.

Expressões Lambda são funções, da forma como aprendemos no Ensino Médio. Para um determinado valor de X, SEMPRE obteremos um determinado resultado Y. Ou seja, dado um valor X, sempre obteremos o MESMO valor de Y. Esse comportamento de uma expressão/função é chamado de imutabilidade, extremamente importante em linguagens funcionais, e que em programação minimiza os bugs relacionados à efeitos colaterais e permite trabalhar com programação paralela e distribuída com mais facilidade.

Quando uma linguagem de programação implementa o uso de expressões lambda, ela permite que a mesma seja tratada como um valor. Ou seja, a função/expressão pode ser colocada em um variável, passada como parâmetro e, normalmente, pode ser usada em loops, em lista de valores e similares, dependendo de como a linguagem implementa o recurso.