# O que são closures e qual sua utilização?

Tags: c#, .net

A resposta desta pergunta sobre lambda [O que são lambda expressions? E qual a sacada em usá-las?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2822) fala sobre closures e expressions tree, contudo, não possui um exemplo claro sobre o que são de fato e qual sua principal utilização. Então, o que são closures e em que situação é importante utilizá-las?

Comment: Relacionado: [closures em Javascript](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1859/como-funcionam-closures-em-javascript) :) BTW +1

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Conceito

**Closure** (ou no português, **clausura**) é uma função que referencia variáveis livres no contexto léxico ([tirei isso deste artigo na Wikipédia](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clausura_(ci%C3%AAncia_da_computa%C3%A7%C3%A3o))). Ou seja, é uma função que referencia, por exemplo, variáveis que não estão declaradas em seu corpo.

Normalmente clausuras são anônimas e existem apenas no corpo de outro método.

Por exemplo:

```
public Fruta FindById(int id)
{
    return this.Find(delegate(Fruta f)
    {
        return (f.Id == id);
    });
}
```

Neste caso, `delegate(Fruta f) { ... }` é uma clausura, que referencia a variável `id` declarada no corpo de `FindById` (outra função).

Uma clausura pode ser atribuída para uma variável:

```
Action acao = delegate { Console.WriteLine(umaStringQualquer); };
```

E ativada em algum momento específico da função ou método:

```
acao();
```

## Utilização

Suponha que vou usar o método `Distinct()` implementado em `IEnumerable` que [exige que seja escrito para ele uma classe de comparação](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms132151(v=vs.110).aspx) como esta:

```
class Comparador : IEqualityComparer<Fruta>
{
    public bool Equals(Fruta x, Fruta y)
    {
        if (x.Nome == y.Nome)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else { return false; }
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Fruta fruta)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Funciona, mas é um pouco prolixo. Com uma clausura, posso utilizar não o `Distinct`, mas uma extensão de classe mais ou menos assim:

```
public List<Fruta> AcharMinhaFruta(Fruta fruta) 
{
    return minhasFrutas.Select(f => delegate (f) { return f.Nome == fruta.Nome; } ).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Existe alguma relação de Closure e Expression trees? Devo abrir uma outra pergunta para o que são expression trees, ou estas estão interligadas com closure, de fato?

Comment: @Vinícius Árvores de Expressão são outras coisas. Melhor abrir outra pergunta.