# Func<T, bool> e Expression<Func<T, bool>>

Tags: c#

Bom gostaria de saber primeiro qual a diferença entre `Func<T, bool>` para `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`

E como eu faço para converter de `Func<T, bool>` para `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` se é possível.

Ou então necessito que todo o meu código fosse Expression ao inves de Func. Porém não sei como Converter e concatenar Expression. No método Filter().

```
public class MovimentoTratamento : Tratamento
{
    public string Nr_Nota_Fiscal { get; set; }
    public string Dt_Emissao_Nota_Fiscal { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Tratamento
{
    [Key]
    public int ID{ get; set; }
    public string Cd_Sap_Distribuidor_Matriz { get; set; }
    public string Cd_Sap_Distribuidor_Filial { get; set; }
    public DateTime Dt_Criacao { get; set; }
    public int Id_Log { get; set; }
}

private Func<Tratamento, bool> FiltroPadrao(FiltroViewModel filtroViewModel)
    {
        DateTime inicial, final;

        DateTime.TryParse(filtroViewModel.CargaInicial, out inicial);
        DateTime.TryParse(filtroViewModel.CargaFinal, out final);

        Func<Tratamento, bool> f = x =>
                                       ((final == DateTime.MinValue) || (x.Dt_Criacao >= inicial && x.Dt_Criacao <= final.AddDays(1)))
                                       &&
                                       (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filtroViewModel.CnpjMatriz) || x.Cd_Sap_Distribuidor_Matriz == filtroViewModel.CnpjMatriz)
                                       &&
                                       (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filtroViewModel.CnpjFilial) || x.Cd_Sap_Distribuidor_Filial == filtroViewModel.CnpjFilial)
                                       &&
                                       (filtroViewModel.TipoErro == "0" || x.Cd_Erro == filtroViewModel.TipoErro)
                                       &&
                                       (
                                            (filtroViewModel.StatusSelected == 3) ||
                                            (filtroViewModel.StatusSelected == 1 && x.Id_Log == 0) ||
                                            (filtroViewModel.StatusSelected == 2 && x.Id_Log > 0)
                                       );
        return f;
    }

    private Func<MovimentoTratamento, bool> FiltroNotaFiscal(FiltroViewModel filtroViewModel)
    {
        return x => (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filtroViewModel.NotaFiscal) || x.Nr_Nota_Fiscal == filtroViewModel.NotaFiscal);
    }

    public IQueryable<MovimentoTratamento> Filter()
    {
        Func<Tratamento, bool> filter = FiltroPadrao(vm);
        Func<MovimentoTratamento, bool> mov = FiltroNotaFiscal(vm);
        UnirExpressionMovimento(filter, mov);
        return repo.Get(f);
    }

    private Func<MovimentoTratamento, bool> UnirExpressionMovimento(Func<Tratamento, bool> filter, Func<MovimentoTratamento, bool> mov)
    {
        Func<MovimentoTratamento, bool> f = value => filter((Tratamento)value);

        return value => f(value) && mov(value);
    }
```

Comment: relacionado, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2822/o-que-s%C3%A3o-lambda-expressions-e-qual-a-sacada-em-us%C3%A1-las/2834#2834

Comment: @DiegoZanardo, por mais que eu tenha tentando lhe ajudar com o seu problema, eu discordo da da sua arquitetura, não acho uma boa ideia implemenar `Repository Pattern` adicionais sobre o `Entity Framework`, você pode ler mais a respeito em [Quando usar Entity Framework com Repository Pattern?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51536/quando-usar-entity-framework-com-repository-pattern#answer-80696)

Comment: ainda abordando este assunto, evite criar algo muito complexo, seria muito mais simples se você realiza-se esta consulta direto sobre o seu `DataSet`, sem a necessidade de criar funções genericas... apesar se não está muito ligado ao seu problema, veja esta materia/video: [A Arquitetura do Stack Overflow e Stack Exchange](http://www.infoq.com/br/presentations/a-arquitetura-do-stack-overflow-e-stack-exchange)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resposta Original: [Why would you use Expression> rather than Func?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793571/why-would-you-use-expressionfunct-rather-than-funct#answer-793584)

Ambas fazem coisas diferentes, enquanto a `Func<T, bool>` representa um codigo que será executado, tanto que o codigo será convertido para linguagem intermediaria e possivelmente executado.

O `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` contem uma representação do que precisa ser feito, e não necessariamente o codigo que será executado, por exemplo, o seguinte trecho de uma consulta usando Entity Framework (TSQL):

```
context.Entities.Where((x) => x.Propriedade1 == x.Propriedade2);
```

No caso acima, o `(x) => x.Propriedade1 == x.Propriedade2` não será executado, mas ele contem informações do que precisa ser feito, neste caso ele será convertido para uma consulta `SQL => SELECT * FROM Entities x WHERE x.Propriedade1 == x.Propriedade2`

Note que o entrada e o resultado de ambos podem até serem iguais, mas à forma como eles trabalham, o codigo compilado e para o que eles são destinados é completamente diferente.

agora voltando ao exemplo acima, caso você queira reutilizar uma `Func<T, bool>` para ser utilizada no Where (que espera um `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`), você terá de fazer um encapsulamente da função:

```
var funcao = new Func<Entity, bool>((x) => x.Propriedade1 == x.Propriedade2);
context.Entities.Where((x) => funcao(x));
```

note que neste caso, a `funcao(x)` não é executada, mas ela contem as "instruções" que a `Expression` precisa, então ela entenderá o que precisa ser feito.

Agora gostaria de falar um pouco da sua implementação e do que eu discordo nela... a primeira coisa é sobre esta variavel `repo`, está a parecer que está utilizando alguma implementação de `Repository Pattern` em conjunto com o `Entity Framework`.

Ao invés disto simplemente utilize o proprio `Entity Framework`, que por sua vez já implementa `Repository Pattern` de uma forma bem mais robusta e completa do que você seria capaz de faze-lo.

Segundo ponto, se realmente deseja isolar trechos de usa consulta para pode reutilizar eles depois, então faça uso de Extensões.

```
public class MovimentoTratamento : Tratamento
{
    public string Nr_Nota_Fiscal { get; set; }
    public string Dt_Emissao_Nota_Fiscal { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Tratamento
{
    [Key]
    public int ID{ get; set; }
    public string Cd_Sap_Distribuidor_Matriz { get; set; }
    public string Cd_Sap_Distribuidor_Filial { get; set; }
    public DateTime Dt_Criacao { get; set; }
    public int Id_Log { get; set; }
}

public static class TratamentoExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<Tratamento> FiltroPadrao(this IQueryable<Tratamento> consulta, FiltroViewModel filtro)
    {
        DateTime inicial, final;
        DateTime.TryParse(filtro.CargaInicial, out inicial);
        DateTime.TryParse(filtro.CargaFinal, out final);

        return consulta.Where(x =>
            ((final == DateTime.MinValue) || (x.Dt_Criacao >= inicial && x.Dt_Criacao <= final.AddDays(1))) &&
            (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filtro.CnpjMatriz) || x.Cd_Sap_Distribuidor_Matriz == filtro.CnpjMatriz) &&
            (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filtro.CnpjFilial) || x.Cd_Sap_Distribuidor_Filial == filtro.CnpjFilial) &&
            (filtro.TipoErro == "0" || x.Cd_Erro == filtro.TipoErro) &&
            ((filtro.StatusSelected == 3) || (filtro.StatusSelected == 1 && x.Id_Log == 0) ||   (filtro.StatusSelected == 2 && x.Id_Log > 0));
    }

    private IQueryable<MovimentoTratamento> FiltroNotaFiscal(this IQueryable<MovimentoTratamento> consulta, FiltroViewModel filtro)
    {
        return consulta.Where(x => (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filtro.NotaFiscal) || x.Nr_Nota_Fiscal == filtro.NotaFiscal));
    }
}

public class TratamentoController
{
    public IQueryable<MovimentoTratamento> Filter(FiltroViewModel filtro)
    {
        using (var context = new MyDbContext())
        {
            return context.MovimentosTratamento.FiltroPadrao(filtro).FiltroNotaFiscal(filtro));
        }
    }
}
```

Os motivos para eu não recomendar o uso de um `Repository Pattern` adicional, você pode ver no seguinte link [Quando usar Entity Framework com Repository Pattern?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51536/quando-usar-entity-framework-com-repository-pattern#answer-80696)

Também recomendo a leitura da seguinte materia: [A Arquitetura do Stack Overflow e Stack Exchange](http://www.infoq.com/br/presentations/a-arquitetura-do-stack-overflow-e-stack-exchange)

Comment: O correto seria então eu converter todo meu código de Func para Expression. Porém em partes do código eu faço concatenação de Func e faço um cast na T. Como faria isso utilizando Expression?

Comment: @DiegoZanardo, você pode tentar chamar a sua `Func<T, bool>` diretamente dentro da `Expression<T, bool>`, mas entenda que isto envolve um risco, afinal alguns trechos de codigos podem não ter uma tradução, por exemplo, ao usar o `Entity Framework` você pode se deparar com um `NotSupportedException` ao usar um bloco de codigo não esperado.

Comment: É exatamente o Entity Framework que estou utilizando. Então isso não vai rolar?

Comment: @DiegoZanardo, você vai precisar testar, caso não funcione, tente identificar o trecho de codigo não suportado.

Comment: Farei este teste em breve... Uma dúvida que fiquei, usando o Entity Framework, passando para ele uma Func, quando for buscar os dados, ele irá trazer todos os registros e então filtrar, ou já vai trazer o resultado filtrado?

Comment: @DiegoZanardo, se fizer um `.Where((x) => funcao(x))`, ele já vai trazer filtrado do banco.

Comment: Deu erro. The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.

Comment: @DiegoZanardo, Como você está utilizando? `.Where(x => FiltroPadrao(filtro)(x))`?

Comment: repo.Get((x) => f(x))