# Como selecionar campos numa consulta em expressão lambda?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, expressões-lambda

Através do `select new` do LINQ eu posso selecionar quais campos serão exibidos na consulta, por exemplo:

```
var subCategorias = from s in db.SubCategoria
                    join c in db.CategoriaProduto 
                        on s.id_categoria equals c.id_categoria
                    where s.descricao.Contains(descricao)
                    select new
                    {
                        Codigo = s.id_sub_categoria,
                        SubCategoria = s.descricao,
                        CodigoCategoria = s.CategoriaProduto.id_categoria,
                        Categoria = s.CategoriaProduto.descricao          
                    };
```

No exemplo acima os campos que estarão disponível após a consulta ser montada pelo método `ToList()` serão os seguintes campos:

> Codigo (id_sub_categoria)
>   SubCategoria (descricao)
>   CodigoCategoria (id_categoria)
>   Categoria (descricao)

Entretanto, eu gostaria de saber como eu posso selecionar os campos que desejo numa consulta feita em expressão lambda ou se existe algum recurso parecido com o `select new` em expressão lambda?

Comment: Isto aí é expressão *lambda*. Quer dizer com sintaxe de método?

Comment: @bigown Sim isso mesmo, sintaxe de método, por exemplo `db.Categoria.First()` desta forma ou outra se houver.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Entenda que o LINQ é uma linguagem só. [Existem duas formas e sintaxe](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14212/101) mas em essência elas executam o mesmo. A sintaxe mais declarativa é um açúcar sintático em cima de métodos existentes. Então o que você faz na forma declarativa pode fazer na forma de método (a grosso modo).

O `select` usado na pergunta é, no fundo, o método [`Select()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_Select__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__) do LINQ. O compilador transforma um jeito de escrever no outro mais "normal" na linguagem C#. Então a única diferença que encontrará é a forma da chamada mesmo. Seria algo assim:

```
.Select(s => new { Codigo = s.id_sub_categoria,
                   SubCategoria = s.descricao,
                   CodigoCategoria = s.CategoriaProduto.id_categoria,
                   Categoria = s.CategoriaProduto.descricao})
```

O que está sendo usado de forma auxiliar nas duas formas é o [tipo anônimo](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Nele você cria um classe *on-the-fly* especificando as propriedades que devem estar disponíveis nela. E já vai inicializando o valor ali mesmo. Ela será preenchida com cada item.

O nome é bem sugestivo para quem está acostumado com o SQL. Essa é a forma de selecionar quais campos deseja. Podendo usar quaisquer expressões válidas na linguagem.

Normalmente usamos `new` para criar uma nova instância de um tipo e em seguida colocamos o nome do tipo e opcionalmente [inicializamos seus valores](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/126348/101), certo? Algo assim:

```
var x = new Tipo { Prop1 = 1, Prop2 = "teste" }; //esta estrutura está definida em Tipo
```

Pois bem, como um tipo anônimo não tem nome e as propriedades podem ser definidas na hora.

```
var x = new { Prop1 = 1, Prop2 = "teste" }; //esta estrutura está sendo "inventada" agora
```

Lembrando que em uma *lambda* não precisamos escrever o `return`, mas se quiséssemos, faríamos assim:

```
.Select(s => return new { Codigo = s.id_sub_categoria,
               SubCategoria = s.descricao,
               CodigoCategoria = s.CategoriaProduto.id_categoria,
               Categoria = s.CategoriaProduto.descricao})
```

Só para mostrar o que é cada coisa, vamos dizer que queira hipoteticamente (porque isto faz pouco sentido) retornar um valor constante:

```
.Select(s => 1)
```

Aqui não usei o tipo anônimo, só o método e passei para ele uma *lambda* bem simples. Na forma declarativa isso seria o mesmo que:

```
select 1
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Linq/ExplainQuery.cs).

Outro exemplo seria um `Select(item => item)` que é o equivalente a um `SELECT *` do SQL. Mas é claro que esse método é totalmente dispensável. Se ele não estiver presente, é exatamente o que será selecionado.

O [`where`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_Where__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Int32_System_Boolean__) é assim. O [`join`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.join?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_Join__4_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___1__System_Func___0___2__System_Func___1___2__System_Func___0___1___3__) também. É tudo assim. [A lista é imensa](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#methods). No entanto nem tudo há uma relação de um para um.

Comment: E se eu quisesse selecionar todos os campos com o método `Select(x =>...)`, parecido com o `select *` do SQL?

Comment: @drmcarvalho `.Select(item => item);`

Comment: @drmcarvalho é isso que o jbueno disse. É claro que essas coisas não fazem tanto sentido usar em um `select`, pelo menos não em condições normais. Pode até haver alguma situação, mas acho que seria mais algo condicional. Este `Select` equivalente ao `*` é o mesmo que não ter o método, ao contrário do SQL onde ele é obrigatório, é a base do comando, o *default* do LINQ é um `select *` por assim dizer. No LINQ declarativo o `from` é a base do comando. No imperativo nem isto é realmente necessário, até um `Select()` sozinho serve, ou um `Where()`, o mais comum.

Answer (score 3):

***Em bem parecido, observe:***

```
.Select(s => new {

});
```

***Completo:***

```
var subCategorias = db.SubCategoria
            .Join(db.CategoriaProduto, c => c.id_categoria, 
                                       a => a.id_categoria, (c,a) => new {c,a})
            .Where(w => w.c.descricao.Contatins(descricao))
            .Select(s => new {
                    Codigo = w.c.id_sub_categoria,
                    SubCategoria = w.c.descricao,
                    CodigoCategoria = w.c.CategoriaProduto.id_categoria,
                    Categoria = w.c.CategoriaProduto.descricao  
            }).ToList();
```

**Explicação:** [O que são expressões lambda?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2834/46523)

Comment: Neste caso eu carrego os campos dentro das chaves { } ?

Comment: Agora entendi rsrs.

Comment: Isso, dentro da chave!