# Quando utilizar os métodos "map()" ou "toList()"?

Tags: método, dart

No exemplo abaixo, os dois métodos basicamente fazem o mesmo trabalho, percorrer a lista de objetos obtendo cada item da lista.

Uma diferença é notada na iteração utilizando `map()`, na ultima ocorrência retorna nulo.

Existe alguma vantagem ou recomendação para utilização de cada um desses métodos? E porque a ultima iteração com `map` retorna nulo?

```
class Produto {
  String nome;
  double quantidade;
}

main() {
  var produtos = List<Produto>();
  var p = Produto();
  p.nome = 'Frango';
  p.quantidade = 2.5;
  produtos.add(p);
  p = Produto();
  p.nome = 'Telha';
  p.quantidade = 1.5;
  produtos.add(p);

  var n = produtos.map((Produto p) {
    print(p);
  });  
  print(n.toList());

  produtos.forEach((p) => print(p));

}
```

```
Resultado map
    Instance of 'Produto'
    Instance of 'Produto'
    [null, null]
____________
Resultado toList()
    Instance of 'Produto'
    Instance of 'Produto'
```

Comment: O método `map` vai transformar um algo em outro algo. No caso, você está mapeando os produtos de uma lista em nada, imprimindo no meio do caminho (uma vez que o [retorno de `print` é `void`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.4.0/dart-core/print.html) e você não especifica retorno)

Comment: Não ajuda o fato de não termos definição da classe `Produto`. Dá pra criar fácil mas ajuda se tivermos ela, o link postado nada tem a ver com isso. Parece que a pergunta tem uma solução procurando um problema, ou seja, viu o tal do `map()` e agora quer usar, isso não costuma ser bom. Inclusive porque vai abusar dele aprendendo assim. O mapa sozinho serve pra nada. Sabe C#, certo? LINQ, certo? o `map()` é o `Select()` do LINQ, ele sozinho serve pra algo útil? Até serve, mas quase sempre um erro usá-lo. LINQ não tem um um `forEach()` Sabe por que? Dart tem, sabe por que?

Comment: @Maniero adicionado, havia esquecido de adicionar.

Comment: Esse foi o exemplo que vi `children: widget.products.map((Product product) {
          return ShoppingListItem(
            product: product,
            inCart: _shoppingCart.contains(product),
            onCartChanged: _handleCartChanged,
          );
        }).toList(),` Fiquei na dúvida por que não forEach()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vou tentar responder a pergunta de uma forma genérica e indicando o que é mais importante, ainda que não dê uma solução específica para o problema, afinal o recurso está sendo usado de forma equivocada e a pergunta não tem informação de como seria o jeito que gostaria de fazer, até porque parece que aprendeu que existe o mecanismo (`map()`) e agora quer aplicá-lo em algum problema que não sabe qual é. No meio do que eu estava escrevendo veio um comentário mostrando que o problema original era outro.

Para o AP (que sei que já perguntou sobre C#) e algumas pessoas vou compara o `map()` com um [`Select()`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/134071/101) do LINQ, ou seja, ele seleciona/mapeia um objeto pegando dados vindos de outro objeto. Pegar dados assim ajuda pouco, espera-se que pelo menos faça alguma operação de manipulação dos membros do objeto quando mapeia para outro objeto.

Não conheço Dart em profundidade, mas acho que vale o mesmo que [já disse várias vezes sobre o abuso de `ToList()` em LINQ](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A101%20%5Blinq%5D%20tolist). As pessoas o usam mais do que deveriam, Ele é uma materializador da lista criada, poque as consultas anteriores não geram uma lista, só geram o algoritmo que ira produzir uma forma de acessar dados manipulados. Se Dart não operasse desse jeito então ela sempre geraria objetos de forma direta e isso seria muito ineficiente ao ponto que eu diria pra jogar essa coisa fora na hora.

É bem simples o uso do `toList()`, você precisa de uma lista agora? Use-o, se não precisa não use. As pessoas criam listas sem precisar, muitas vezes porque ela só segue a receita de bolo. Se você só precisa acessar dados manipulados que vieram de uma outra coleção de dados não tem como criar uma lista. Eu acredito que isso vem do mesmo erro que faz as pessoas criarem variáveis sem necessidade, elas não entendem o que está fazendo ali e acham que se não criar a variável algo dará errado, ela acha que precisa ter um nome indicando que você tem um objeto. Então a pessoa acha que pra acessar os dados manipulados tem que criar uma lista. Só crie uma lista se o que quer agora é exatamente uma lista, nem mais, nem menos que isto.

Eu questiono inclusive a existência do `forEach()` na linguagem. Sabe porque tem isso? Por que a linguagem não tem uma construção abstrata imperativa que percorra um coleção de dados, ou você usa um `for` bruto, ou usa esse método. O problema dele é que incentiva as pessoas usarem o jeito funcional em uma linguagem imperativa, e algumas construções podem ser confusas para quem não está acostumado com o jeito funcional. Escopo de variável pode ser um problema, assim como desviar a execução não é possível igual ao jeito imperativo complicado certas situações. Existe um motivo que o LINQ não tem `ForEach()`, ele forma espertos.

Então esse código faz sentido (ele obtém os valores totais do estoque, note que não criei lista alguma, só peguei os dados da lista de objetos existente):

```
import 'dart:io';
 
class Produto {
    String nome;
    double quantidade;
    double valor;
}

main() {
    var produtos = List<Produto>();
    var p = Produto();
    p.nome = 'Frango';
    p.quantidade = 2.5;
    p.valor = 10.0;
    produtos.add(p);
    p = Produto();
    p.nome = 'Telha';
    p.quantidade = 1.5;
    p.valor = 20.0;
    produtos.add(p);
    var totais = produtos.map((Produto p) => p.valor * p.quantidade);  
    totais.forEach((p) => print(p));
}
```

Se Dart for eficiente tem quase o mesmo custo (mas não o mesmo porque tem o custo da abstração, só não mudará a [complexidade de algoritmo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/33319/101)) de fazer este código:

```
import 'dart:io';
 
class Produto {
    String nome;
    double quantidade;
    double valor;
}

main() {
    var produtos = List<Produto>();
    var p = Produto();
    p.nome = 'Frango';
    p.quantidade = 2.5;
    p.valor = 10.0;
    produtos.add(p);
    p = Produto();
    p.nome = 'Telha';
    p.quantidade = 1.5;
    p.valor = 20.0;
    produtos.add(p);
    for (var i = 0; i < produtos.length; i++) print(produtos[i].valor * produtos[i].quantidade);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/yHRYGo). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/MapExampledt). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Dart/MapExample.dt).

Eu tenho sempre que falar sobre o [uso de `double` em valor monetário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/101) porque alguém irá ler isso e achará que está correto usá-lo. Também não posso deixar de citar o [construtor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101) porque alguém pode achar que este exemplo é bom (ele é simplificado só para usar o mecanismo, nesse contexto é aceitável fazer assim).

Comment: No [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/) tem um [pacote para `decimal`](https://pub.dev/packages/decimal). Não fui atrás a fundo de saber como é a implementação interna dele, mas me lembou o `BigDecimal` do Java. Portanto, ponto arbitrário e comprimento arbitrário.

Comment: É, parece a mesma Gambiarra, tá difícil gostar de alguma coisa que vem da Google. Dart já deu sinais que tem muita coisa de qualquer jeito, nasceu outro dia e já está cansada.

Comment: Sobre a "esperteza" do Dart: pelo que li, é o mesmo comportamento que o `Stream` usa no Java 8 ou os diversos _comprehension_ do Python, só executa no momento que necessita, não pré-carregando nada.

Comment: Só poderia, caso contrário, é o que eu disse, joga fora.

Comment: Impressão minha ou chamou o `BigDecimal` do Java de gambiarra? Ou a existência de pacotes de fácil publicação estilo NPM-hell de gambiarra?

Comment: Ambos :D Mas olha o `decimal` do C# e verá como é muito melhor, ainda que pra mim seja meio defeituoso também :)

Comment: conheço só o `decimal` do SQL-Server e mesmo assim mal. Creio ser equivalente ao do C#. Se for, é o bom e velho ponto fixo, com bitagem definida. Tem vantagens e desvantagens, mas matematicamente acho o modelo de ponto arbitrário de bitagem variada mais elegante, mesmo reconhecendo que casos _business_ de aplicação necessária sejam escassos.