# Modificar método genérico para unir informações em classes

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, genéricos

Estou sou marinheiro de primeira viagem com o EntityFramework e estou trabalhando com uma classe `USUARIO` que herda de `PESSOA`.

Existem outras classes como `PESSOATIPO`, `PESSOAFISICA`, `PESSOAJURIDICA`, etc., o problema é que quando eu carrego meu `DataGridView`, o EntityFramework não consegue separar os dados de cada tabela e posicionar os campos corretamente dentro das linhas. Veja como `PESSOAFISICA` ficou deveriam ser apresentados os campos `NOMECOMPLETO`, `APELIDO` E `DATANASCIMENTO`.

> [image: Tabela]

Isso ocorre porque tenho uma função genérica que me retorna isso tudo. Gostaria de saber se dá para *implementar/alterar* a função abaixo para passar algum tipo de `select` (`Lambda`) para ele me devolver colunas na ordem que eu quiser, e assim o `DataGridview` ser carregado corretamente e o carregamento ter uma performance boa?

**Exemplo:**

```
Usuario.Select(x=> x.USuarioId, 
               x.PessoaFisica.NomeCompleto, 
               x.PessoaFisica.Apelido, 
               x.PessoaFisica.DataNascimento).
```

ou seja, algo assim.

```
public List<TEntity> GetAll(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> Predicate)
{
    var query = Context.Set<TEntity>().Where(Predicate).ToList();
    return query;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sim, existe uma maneira te trazer uma lista com tipo criado em tempo de execução (*pode ser criado também um classe que represente esse novo modelo de dados*), crie um método com o código abaixo, onde `TResult` é um novo tipo de dado que será criado na saída e pode atribuir a nova lista no `DataGridView`

```
public List<TResult> GetAll<TResult>(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate, 
                                     Expression<Func<TEntity, TResult>> select)
{
    var query = Context.Set<TEntity>()
                       .Where(predicate)
                       .Select(select) 
                       .ToList();
    return query;
}
```

---

Na chamada do método seria:

```
.GetAll(x => x.UsuarioId == 1, s = new {
        s.UsuarioId, ... //e continua colocando os dados da relação e precisa
});
```

<sub>**Observação:** acredito que deva implementar o método na `interface` para se propagar nas classes que a implementam.</sub>

**Referencias:**

- [Expression Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.aspx?PHPSESSID=tn8k5...)
- [O que são expressões lambda?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2834/54880)
- [Pass in an Expression to linq's Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9744055/pass-in-an-expression-to-linqs-select)
- [Introdução a consultas LINQ (C#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb397906.aspx)
- [Operações de consulta LINQ básica (C#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-BR/library/bb397927.aspx)

Comment: Virgilio, estou com uma dúvida sobre criar essa tal classe TResult... Na minha classe genérica, todas as funções retornam um TEntity, Mas com TResult eu não sei como implementar... Vc teria como exemplificar?

Comment: @JalberRomano nesse caso que eu coloquei na resposta você não precisa fazer nada é só chamar o `GetAll` e passar as duas expressão como está no exemplo, ele se encarrega de trazer esse `TResult` conforme a sua seleção (Select) de dados. Você mesmo já fez logo acima um Select é bem parecido no segundo paramento dessa função que está na resposta