# Passar uma instrução lambda por parametro - C# - Entity

Tags: c#, select, expressões-lambda, join

Tenho uma método no qual preciso passar apenas um select por parametro:

```
public List<TEntity> GetAll(Expression<Func<TEntity, TEntity>> Select)
{
    var query = Context.Set<TEntity>()
                .Where()
                .Select(Select).ToList();
    return query;
}
```

Preciso passar um select que me traga os seguintes campos: `UsuarioId, Login, Senha, UsuarioTipoId e Descricao`. Seria algo mais ou menos como a seguir:

```
dgPesquisar.DataSource = UsuarioRepositorio.GetAll(u => new 
    { 
        x.UsuarioId, 
        x.Login, 
        x.Senha, 
        x.UsuarioTipoId, 
        x.Descricao
     });
```

**É necessário fazer algum Join nas tabelas?**

Alguém saberia como me ajudar montar a expressão e como passá-la por parâmetro?

```
//Classes:
public class UsuarioTipoModel
{
    public int UsuarioTipoId { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UsuarioModel> Usuario { get; set; }
}

public class UsuarioModel : PessoaModel
{
    public string Login { get; set; }
    public string Senha { get; set; }
    public int UsuarioTipoId { get; set; }

    public virtual UsuarioTipoModel UsuarioTipo { get; set; }

}
```

**Repositório**

```
public abstract class BaseRepository<TEntity> : Interfaces.IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    private DbContext Context = null;
    protected DbSet<TEntity> Entity = null;

    public BaseRepository(DbContext Context)
    {
        this.Context = Context;
        this.Entity = Context.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public void Add(TEntity Entity)
    {
        Context.Set<TEntity>().Add(Entity);
        Context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Delete(TEntity Entity)
    {
        Context.Set<TEntity>().Remove(Entity);
        Context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public TEntity Find(int Id)
    {
        var query = Context.Set<TEntity>().Find(Id);
        return query;
    }

    public List<TEntity> GetAll()
    {
        var query = Context.Set<TEntity>().ToList();
        return query;
    }

    public List<TEntity> GetAll(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> Predicate)
    {
        var query = Context.Set<TEntity>().Where(Predicate).ToList();
        return query;
    }

    public List<TEntity> GetAll(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> Predicate, Expression<Func<TEntity, TEntity>> Select)
    {
        var query = Context.Set<TEntity>()
            .Where(Predicate)
            .Select(Select).ToList();
        return query;
    }

    public void Update(TEntity Entity)
    {
        Context.Entry(Entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
        Context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: Você pode postar a sua classe Repositório por completo?

Comment: Blz.. Acabei de Atualizar.....

Comment: @JalberRomando, porque você não segui o método que eu te passei na primeira questão? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/163712/modificar-m%C3%A9todo-gen%C3%A9rico-para-unir-informa%C3%A7%C3%B5es-em-classes-c-windows-forms , você não está entendendo?

Comment: Opa.... É que não consegui entender direito o tipo  TResult... Seria criar uma nova classe com esse nome? Éuma classe do Entity? No meu projeto ela fica sublinhada de vermelho....

Comment: @JalberRomano Estude generics. Uma **dica**: esqueça o uso de *repository* com Entity Framework. Você nunca teria passado por este problema se não usasse este *pattern* "em cima" do EF

Comment: `TResult` seria um dado criado em tempo de execução ou pode ser um modelo criado por uma determinada classe, ou seja, não é obrigado criar uma classe pra esse modelo, mas, pode ser criado. `List<TResult> GetAll<TResult>(Expression<Func<TEntity, TResult>> select)` se tiver sublinhado em vermelho talvez precisa indicar que TResult é uma classe, se está com problemas nisso ainda?

Comment: Olá Virgilio... entendi a Ideia... Estou retornando um UsuarioModel. Até aí tudo certo. A minha classe UsuarioModel herda de PessoaModel, e PessoaModel Possui um relacioamento de composicao com PessoaFisicaModel e PessoaJuridicaModel.... O método GetAll já me traz tudo certinho, todos os registros. minha dúvida seria: Como eu passo uma instrução Lambda oara o GetAll me trazer apenas alguns campos de cada tabela? ex: dgUsuario.DataSource = UsuarioRepositorio.GetAll("NÃO SEI COMO FAZER UM SELECT LAMBDA AQUI")....

Answer (score 1):

Para poder dizer com mais certeza como ficaria o código no seu contexto vou precisar da classe completa de repositório do Usuário. Mas segue abaixo uma ideia de como pode ser feita a declaração do método e o seu uso.

A declaração do método seria da seguinte forma:

```
public List<TResult> GetAll<TResult>(Expression<Func<TEntity, TResult>> select)
{
    var query = Context.Set<TEntity>()
        .Include("UsuarioTipo")
        .Select(select)
        .ToList();
    return query;
}
```

A chamada do método seria da seguinte forma:

```
UsuarioRetornoModel usuarioRetorno = UsuarioRepositorio.GetAll<UsuarioRetornoModel>(u => new UsuarioRetornoModel 
    { 
        UsuarioId = u.UsuarioId, 
        Login = u.Login, 
        Senha = u.Senha, 
        UsuarioTipoId = u.UsuarioTipo.UsuarioTipoId, 
        UsuarioTipoDescricao = u.UsuarioTipo.Descricao
     }
);
```

A classe de retorno:

```
public class UsuarioRetornoModel
{
    public int UsuarioId { get; set; }
    public string Login { get; set; }
    public string Senha { get; set; }
    public int UsuarioTipoId { get; set; }
    public string UsuarioTipoDescricao { get; set; }
}
```

### Atualizado

As propriedades `UsuarioId`, `Login`, `Senha`, `UsuarioTipoId` e `UsuarioTipoDescricao` foram consideradas como propriedades da classe UsuarioRetornoModel e o `u` dentro da expressão lambda estaria relacionado a entidade do usuário. Para acessar propriedades de objetos que provêm de uma relação de chave estrangeira é necessário fazer o uso do include. Foi passado o nome da propriedade dentro do include `Include("UsuarioTipo")`.

### Atualizado II

Certifique-se de implementar o método na interface.

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity>
{
    ...
    List<TResult> GetAll<TResult>(Expression<Func<TEntity, TResult>> select);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Uma pergunta, aonde está `DataSource`?

Comment: Eu segui o código que foi passado na pergunta para fazer o exemplo de uso e considerei as propriedades que eu acredito que tenham dentro deste objeto.

Comment: eu não estou criticando, é uma observação, o usuário está com dificuldades, e é bem ai, inclua uma `classe` `DataSource` (eu mudaria o nome já visto que no mundo net esse nome pode ser confuso, por existir em vários contextos) para o usuário entender aonde fica cada coisa!

Comment: Beleza! Obrigado pelo seu feedback. Vou editar a resposta.

Comment: Ah só lembrando a sua resposta está correta, eu já tinha feito pra ele aqui, mas, não sei o porque de não utilizar: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/163712/modificar-m%C3%A9todo-gen%C3%A9rico-para-unir-informa%C3%A7%C3%B5es-em-classes-c-windows-forms

Comment: `IRepository` alerte ele também que o método deve estar contido na `Interface`, pode ser isso também a confusão.

Comment: Talvez ele ainda esteja com dificuldade na questão do retorno.