# Como embaralhar lista de strings em c#?

Tags: c#, lista, console

Tenho uma aplicação console, na qual existe a lista:

```
List <string> ListaFrases = new List<string>();
```

Essa lista é construída através dos inputs do usuário no console. Como exibir suas strings, porém de forma que a posição das mesmas sejam "embaralhadas", ou seja, exibidas em ordem aleatória?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a classe `Random`.
Ela faz uma randomização simples, mas efetiva.

**Exemplo:**

```
List <string> ListaFrases = new List<string>(); 
var rnd = new Random(); // Randomizador

// Cria uma nova lista com as frases embaralhadas.
var ListaFrasesRandom = ListaFrases.OrderBy(x => rnd.Next()).ToList();
```

Ou se quiser apenas exibir a lista embaralhada ao invés de criar uma lista nova.

```
ListaFrases.OrderBy(x => rnd.Next()).ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

[Veja funcionando no .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zhbWhf)

Comment: Isto gera sorteio sem repetição? Ou os elementos podem ser repetidos? Pois a intenção seria a de um sorteio sem repetição.

Comment: Sem repetição, o `OrderBy` caminha  pela lista e muda a ordem de cada item apenas uma vez, sem gerar duplicidade.

Comment: Como entender a lógica deste trecho?                                                           
    x => rnd.Next())

Comment: `rnd.Next()` vai te fornecer um numero aleatório. O `x` é o item da sua lista de strings. O `OrderBy(x => rnd.Next())` está falando que cada item (`x`) vai ser ordenado por um número aleatório `rnd.Next()`, então, por exemplo, o item 1 vai receber o numero 76 e o item 2 o numero 31, fazendo com que eles fiquem em ordens diferentes.

Comment: Certo, mas eu pensava que x => rnd.Next() seria algo como "x será maior ou igual a aleatório. Não entendi muito bem a lógica

Comment: Ah, isso é um assunto complexo de começo. Isso se chama expressões lamda (lambda expressions). Olhe só a explicação neste post https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2822/o-que-são-lambda-expressions-e-qual-a-sacada-em-usá-las