# Lambda no Python - Dúvida

Tags: python, python-3.x

Em estudo sobre python 3, qual seria a função do lambda no Python, para que ele serve e quando é utilizado?

Comment: Relacionada: [O que são lambda expressions? E qual a sacada em usá-las?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2822/5878)

Answer (score 2):

Lambda são funções de uma linha (geralmente, chamadas uma única vez). São conhecidas como funções anonimas em algumas linguagens. Vc pode querer utilizar lambdas quando vc não precisa usar uma função por mais de uma vez em um programa. Elas funcionam como uma função regular.

Sintaxe:

```
lambda arguments: manipulate(arguments)
```

**Exemplo:**

```
# Definindo uma função regular 
deff add(x , y):
    return x+y

# A mesma função com lambda
add = lambda x, y: x+y
```

Para chama-la, use a mesma sintaxe para a chamada da função regular, por exemplo:

```
print(add(3, 7))
# output: 10
```

No exemplo acima, a função foi criada e atribuida a uma variável, nesse caso, poderia-se utiliza-la mais de uma vez, mas na maioria das vezes `lambdas` são executadas "inline", descartadas após o uso, como nos exemplos de `map()` e `filter()`, em seguida.

Funcoes lambdas são geralmente utilizadas em python como argumento para funcoes "de ordem superior" (funções que recebem outras funcoes como parte dos argumentos), bastante utilizadas como funções internas de `filter()` e  `map()`.

**Exemplo utilizando `filter()`**

A funçõa `filter()` em python recebe em seus argumento um função e uma lista e retorna uma nova lista contendo os itens que a função avalia como `True`.

```
mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
newlist = list(filter(lambda x: (x%2 == 0) , mylist))

print(newlist)
[2, 4, 6]
```

**Exemplo utilizando `map()`**

A função map recebe uma lista e uma função e retorna uma nova lista na qual os elementos são resultantes da aplicação da função enviada em cada elemento da lista recebida.

```
mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
newlist = list(map(lambda x: x*2, mylist))

print(newlist)
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12]
```

**List Comprehensions**

Sempre que sentir a necessidade de usar lambda em que o retorno seja uma lista, veja se não é possível usar as `Lists comprehensions`, são muito mais elegantes, intuitivas e pythonicas, veja os mesmos exemplos com elas:

```
# List comprehension like a filter()
mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
newlist1 = [n for n in mylist if (n%2==0)]
print(newlist1)
[2, 4, 6]

# List comprehension like a map()
newlist2 = [n*2 for n in mylist1]
print(newlist2)
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12]
```

Answer (score 0):

Lambda é uma função definida no runtime (tempo de execução) do programa. Ele pode ser utilizado para simplificar algumas operações, mas mais que isso lambdas trazem uma semântica funcional a linguagem, na qual você trabalha com objetos e funções, um exemplo de utilização do lambda seria pegar um vetor de números e multiplica-los por 2.

Com o lambda não é necessário realizar um loop explícito:

```
items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
squared = []

for i in items:
    squared.append(i**2)

print ("squared =", squared)
vc pode usar a função map

def square(x):
    return x**2
items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
squared = list(map(square, items))
print ("squared =", squared)
ou vc pode criar um lambda diretamente

items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
squared = list(map(lambda x: x**2, items))
print ("squared =", squared)
```

Comment: >Lambda é uma função definida no runtime (tempo de execução) do programa - o que isso significa exatamente? Não é o caso pra todas as funções?